# Data missing after ZFS replication on FreeNAS/TrueNAS

Tags: zfs, replication, encryption, truenas

In order to use the new encryption method in TrueNAS 12 I copied all data from a legacy encrypted FreeNAS pool to a newly formatted pool via a replication task.

After replication there seems to be almost a GiB missing on the target pool:

Source pool after replication:
8.06 TiB used, 733.91 GiB available

Target pool after replication:
7.24 TiB used, 1.56 TiB available

For replication I used these settings (basic mode):

- source/target “On this System”
- [left “Recursive” and “Replicate Custom Snapshots” unchecked (because I didn’t use snapshots)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pH9EH.png)
- [left “Encryption” unchecked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOqdX.png)
- [Replication Schedule: Run Once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YineN.png)
- [unchecked “Make Destiation Dataset Read-only”](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YineN.png)
- [Destination Snapshot Life Time: Same as Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YineN.png)

To find out what is missing a `diff` would take too long.

I tried `rsync -avun --delete $TARGET $SOURCE  | grep "^deleting "` but there was no output.

What else could I do to check for the missing files on the target in reasonable time? Is there something ZFS-related that might take up space and hasn’t been copied over by the replication task? What could that be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference can be related to different pool or dataset configuration (mirror vs raidz, ashift value, recordsize, compression, etc). If you sent data via `send/recv`, no data should be lost ever. This seems confirmed by the output of your `rsync` command.

If you can, please show the output of the following commands on both source and destination (feel free to redact the output as required):

```
zpool status
zpool get all
zfs get all
```

Comment: Thanks for these commands! Comparing `zfs get all` shows that `zstd_compress` is disabled on the source and enabled on the target. Guess that’s the solution.

Comment: What is `send/recv`? Does ZFS replication (configured from TrueNAS web UI) use this?

Comment: @Andept yeah, if compression is enabled on the target only, this easily explain the different size. `zfs send` and `zfs recv` are the ZFS native tools for filesystem replication, and TrueNAS replication should use them as far I know.